# Which language is this language heard in many urban songs?

Tags: lyrics

In many urban songs I hear a language which is unintelligible. I thought that it could be some jamaican creole since urban reggaeton influenced songs are historically linked to jamaican reggae. But I have no idea if this is so. 
What's this language?

[Daddy Yankee - Con Calma](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiItGE3eAyQ&t=2m33s)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like Jamaican English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not surprising you had difficultly understanding this.  He is rapping both in Spanish and English, both accented to sound like Jamaican patois, including some vocabulary not found in standard American or British English.